# Как удалить Ubuntu, не стерев GRUB?

Tags: ubuntu

Есть на одном жёстком диске винда, дебьян и убунта. Последней устанавливалась она. Поэтому если я удалю раздел вместе с ней, то есть опасность, что не смогу загружать другие разделы. Подскажите, что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишите в консоли

```
fdisk -l
```

И посмотрите, какой раздел помечен как загружаемый. Вот в него и установлен у вас груб (поправьте, если вру). Да и как писали выше, если и затрете груб - восстановите с lifeCD, это 5 минут работы. Удачи :)

Answer (score 1):

Снесите убунту, если все-таки граб каким-то образом потрется, то просто установите его с лайв-сиди и все.